# Canot find module used in custom angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

I'm building a custom library with angular so that I can create components in this library that will be re-used through many future applications. I began with creating a few components and a couple services. One of the services requires a dependency of `oidc-client`. So inside my library I ran an `npm install oidc-client`. The dependency was added under my libraries `package.json` `dependencies` section. I began getting errors, read some of the documentation and found that this should actually be under the `peerDependencies` section, and not the `dependencies` section of my libraries package.json.

My folder/file layout is as so

```
./
../
.editorconfig
.gitignore
angular.json
dist/
node_modules/
package.json
package-lock.json
projects/
projects/my-lib/
projects/my-lib-runner/
README.md
tsconfig.base.json
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

What I do to test run my library is do a

```
ng build my-lib --watch
```

in one terminal, and then in another I run

```
ng serve my-lib-runner
```

When I run the `-runner` is when I get this error

```
ERROR in dist/my-lib/lib/core/services/auth.service.d.ts:2:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'oidc-client' orr its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { User } from 'oidc-client';
```

And then here's the `package.json` for `projects/my-lib/`

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I thought as a peer dependency, the project that references the library would either automatically download the necessary package on `npm install` or it would be included in the `npm install my-lib`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PeerDependencies are not installed automatically. You need to install them yourself in the app that consumes the library.

Comment: @MikeOne ok I see. I had the impression that defining that as a dev dependency would load it when I `npm install`ed my package.